# How to implement Count method on Mocked IQueryable object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, unit-testing, moq

Currently, I'm mocking up a DbSet using:

```
//Helper Function in another file
public static DbSet<T> MockDbSet<T>(params T[] items) where T : class
            {
                IEnumerable<T> ts = items;
                var mock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
                mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(ts.GetEnumerator());
                return mock.Object;
            }
```

And I'm calling it using:

```
Answer[] sampleAnswers = new Answer[]
                {
                    new Answer() { Id = 4, QuestionId = 1, SurveyId = 4 },
                    new Answer() { Id = 5, QuestionId = 2, SurveyId = 4 },
                    new Answer() { Id = 6, QuestionId = 3, SurveyId = 4 },
                    new Answer() { Id = 7, QuestionId = 4, SurveyId = 5 }
                };

var mockAnswers = Helper.MockDbSet(sampleAnswers);

context.Setup(c => c.Answers).Returns(mockAnswers);
var count = context.Object.Answers.Count();
```

When I get to context.Object.Answers.Count() I get a null pointer exception. However, when I run a foreach over context.Object.Answers, I'm able to get each answer fine. Is there something I'm missing that I need to mock? I know I can't mock extension methods.

Comment: Look at all of the members that `IQueryable<T>` has.  Assume that the various consumers of that interface will need all of them, because most of them *will* need all of them.  Testing that one of the members is there doesn't change the fact that others are being used, and you did not provide a definition for them.

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement setting up the provider, element, and expression but would I need to change my helper function to expect a type that implements IQueryable? I was hoping to keep it general IEnumerable types..

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Comment: You have to setup the Count method for mockAnswers.

Comment: You shouldn’t put the answer into your question....You can answer your question in in an answer or ask @Servy to do it.

Comment: Good point sorry still learning. Ask @servy to make his comment an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Servy's answer was right I needed to change my generic DbSet to the following and count worked:

```
 public static DbSet<T> MockDbSet<T>(params T[] items) where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> ts = items;
        var mock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(ts.GetEnumerator());
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(items.AsQueryable().Provider);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(items.AsQueryable().Expression);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(items.AsQueryable().ElementType);

        return mock.Object;
    }
```